# Why do I get the "Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed" error when traversing the call stack via keyboard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

I understand what the error message is intended for, i.e. that you can't use the Edit and Continue feature in 64-bit mode.

But I get the error just when traversing the call stack.

It only happens when I use the keyboard and after I press <kbd>Return</kbd> to jump to a location in the call stack.

But it only happens intermittently, i.e. I can jump to several places fine and then the next place I'll get the error; it's like the IDE is processing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key twice, i.e. jumping and then trying to insert a newline.

Is there some different way to use the keyboard to jump through the call stack (without errors), or why am I getting this error?

EDIT: It only seems to happen when my current call stack location and my target call stack location are both in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 - after testing on VS 2012, I don't see this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have received this error but only when I forget to stop debugging before changing things. So I would check to make sure you are no longer debugging.

Comment: I'm not trying to change any code, just to jump through the call stack several times (using cursor up/down and the return key).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a dodgy return key on your keyboard - like you say, you are occasionally getting more than one return - I'd try swapping out the keyboard and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get double Return key presses at any other time, i.e. I've never seen double newlines being registered when I'm writing code.

Comment: This sound facetious, but it's not :) Could it be that when you're debugging and walking the stack, you hit the return key harder than normal?!? Just a thought...

Comment: :) Ok, I tried it again just now, and pressed the keys very softly but still get the problem.  Have you tried it and don't get any problem?  I assumed it was a Visual Studio issue, but maybe it's something local to my machine.

Comment: Just tried it - I get it occasionally too - but I think in my case it was because I was clicking on a line, then hitting return, clicking on a line etc etc, and I got out of sequence, so that I was hitting return twice.

Comment: I think I spotted a pattern now, I get it when I am jumping to a different place in the call stack which is in the same file, i.e. if I am currently in the call stack in file X, and I jump to a different place in the call stack which is also in file X then I get the error, if the call stack destination is in a different file, then I don't get the error.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing that - found a place where I have two functions in the same file, in the stack, and flip between them repeatedly (ctrl d ctrl c to select the stack window, cursor key, then return) - nothing - it works for me!

Comment: Bummer, are you using VS 2010?  I don't remember getting this before VS 2010.

Comment: VS 2012 - should have mentioned that before - maybe it's fixed in 2012.

Comment: Thanks, that might be it.  I think we will upgrade to 2012 at some point, guess I'll have to live with it until then.

Comment: Cool, I'll post that as an answer then, for others.